# javax @POST @Consumes and @PathParam

Tags: java, rest, post, servlets, path

I'm trying to process JSON via a `POST` request, and the endpoint should be able to get also a `@PathParam` as below, so that the method is passed both the path parameter and the JSON object, but my application is returing a 404.

If I remove the `@PathParam` altogether everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

```
// This is ignored when i call `POST example.com/endpoint/42` and returns a 404
@POST @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("endpoint/{param}")
public List<MyResult> myRequestMethod( @PathParam("param") int p, MyJsonRequest j) {        
        // ... use p & j
}

// This works provided I remove the other above 
@POST @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("endpoint}")
public List<MyResult> myRequestMethod( MyJsonRequest j) {        
        // ... use j
}

// This works as well
@GET
@Path("similar/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<MyResult> otherMethod(
        @PathParam("id") long id) {
          // ...
}
```

Comment: Do you mean @PathVariable?

Comment: what do you mean t by this `If I remove the @PathParam altogether everything works fine`

Comment: You definitely missing one forward slash in the path '/endpoint/{param}', and if you have all desired dependencies in classpath it should work.

Comment: I've added other examples of things that work

Comment: This isn't normal behavior. You will need to provide an [MCVE] so that we can test it. Everything we would need to reproduce the problem, add that to your post. That includes dependencies, app configuration, and complete resource class with import statements.

Comment: Thanks, It is good to know that this should just work. I will isolate the code and see what breaks it.